# Not able to set Microsoft Graph permissions in Azure Active Directory App Registration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-cloud-services

I created a new Azure subscription (free) and under the Default directory registered a new Cloud Service ASP.Net MVC Web Application. I also added a new user to the default domain. When I run the application everything works in the application connected with this Azure AD.

Now when I try to set permissions for Microsoft Graph I see no permissions there. And thats why my User.IsInRole and IsAuthenticated doesn't work.

Both the users in the Default directory are Global Administrators - [Error message in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GuUo.png)

User 1 (amanpreet.singh@hotmail.com) - this created the free subscription

User 2 (amanpsingh@amanpreetsinghhotmail.onmicrosoft.com) - added by User 1

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known error right now in the Azure portal, and we are working on a fix right now.

For the time being, you can use our other app registration portals to manage your application configuration settings: The [App Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com) or our old [Azure UX](https://manage.windowsazure.com).

Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks for your response. While I did try with the old Azure UX and could not add Microsoft Graphs. Got this error - "Could not update the configuration for app". This issue that I am getting is with the free subscription but not with my Organization's subscription. Is that the underlying cause ?